# Magento 2 sort by Rating not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I have added sort by rating on the category page and Magento version 2.4.2, However, it's not working.
I'm doing this using a plugin `di.xml` code

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="Apr_Work::addNewFilterInToolbar" type="Aspl\Work\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
    </type>
```

I have added around method as follow:

```
public function aroundSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $collection
    ) {     
        $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
        $currentDirection = $subject->getCurrentDirection();
        
        $result = $proceed($collection);
        
        if ($currentOrder == self::RATING_SORT_BY) { 
            $subject->getCollection()->getSelect()
                    ->joinLeft(
                            'kliv_review_entity_summary',
                            'e.entity_id = kliv_review_entity_summary.entity_pk_value'
                        )
            ->group('e.entity_id')
            ->order('rating_summary desc');
           # echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString(); die;
        }elseif ($currentOrder == self::HTOL_SORT_BY) {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'desc');
        } elseif ($currentOrder == self::LTOH_SORT_BY) {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('price', 'asc');
        }
 
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem, the result set that is rendered in `list.phtml` or something else?

Comment: Yes, it's for list.phtml

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change collection that is passed to `view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` you will need different approach.

And the reason why is although that collection is passed to:
`\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar` it is first set in: `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
        $this->_productCollection = $this->initializeProductCollection();
    }

    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

So when `$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();` is called in list.phtml it returns what was initialized in `ListProduct` class.

As a possible solution you could add observer for `catalog_block_product_list_collection` which is declared in: `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct::initializeProductCollection`

That would give you collection that's initialized and passed to `list.phtml`

For reference you can look into core magento reviews module that hooks into the same event:

```
    <event name="catalog_block_product_list_collection">
        <observer name="review" instance="Magento\Review\Observer\CatalogProductListCollectionAppendSummaryFieldsObserver" shared="false" />
    </event>
```